# Magent2.3: Advanced Seacrh is not working

Tags: magento2.3, plugin, advanced-search

I have installed the Amasty Advanced search module in Magento 2 cloud and its not working, I'm getting the below error in the log:

> [app/code/Amasty/Xsearch/Helper/Data.php:144]\n#20
>   Amasty\Xsearch\Helper\Data->_pushItem() called at
>   [app/code/Amasty/Xsearch/Helper/Data.php:173]\n#21
>   Amasty\Xsearch\Helper\Data->getBlocksHtml() called at
>   [app/code/Amasty/Xsearch/Controller/Autocomplete/Index.php:135]\n#22
>   Amasty\Xsearch\Controller\Autocomplete\Index->execute() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]\n#23
>   Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#24
>   Amasty\Xsearch\Controller\Autocomplete\Index\Interceptor->___callParent()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#25
>   Amasty\Xsearch\Controller\Autocomplete\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-customer-segment/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php:81]\n#26
>   Magento\CustomerSegment\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#27
>   Amasty\Xsearch\Controller\Autocomplete\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-company/Plugin/Framework/App/Action/AbstractActionPlugin.php:65]\n#28
>   Magento\Company\Plugin\Framework\App\Action\AbstractActionPlugin->aroundDispatch()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#29
>   Amasty\Xsearch\Controller\Autocomplete\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#30
>   Amasty\Xsearch\Controller\Autocomplete\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
>   called at
>   [generated/code/Amasty/Xsearch/Controller/Autocomplete/Index/Interceptor.php:26]\n#31
>   Amasty\Xsearch\Controller\Autocomplete\Index\Interceptor->dispatch()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]\n#32
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:98]\n#33
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#34
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#35
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]\n#36 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#37
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/fastly/magento2/Model/FrontControllerPlugin.php:120]\n#38
>   Fastly\Cdn\Model\FrontControllerPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#39
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [app/code/Amasty/InvisibleCaptcha/Plugin/Predispatch.php:112]\n#40
>   Amasty\InvisibleCaptcha\Plugin\Predispatch->aroundDispatch() called
>   at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#41
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]\n#42
>   Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#43
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#44
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
>   called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]\n#45
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
>   called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]\n#46
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#47
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at
>   [pub/index.php:40]\n","url":"/amasty_xsearch/autocomplete/index/?q=oled&uenc=aHR0cDovL2ludGVncmF0aW9uLTVvam15dXEtNHc0c3B1YzNmaHY3by5hcC0zLm1hZ2VudG9zaXRlLmNsb3VkL3RlbGV2aXNpb24uaHRtbA%2C%2C&_=1581942375456","script_name":"/index.php","report_id":"16072f4a0e383e0b6357887180fadcabf3be1f7df986eb768e621ebd2d5f5aeb"}

Could anyone please help me to know what the error is about?